# Xamarin Forms ContentPage predictive text or word bar at the base of page - what is it and how to remove?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Anyone know what the official name of this bar is at the base of a Xamarin Forms ContentPage? If so, how is it removed? Tinkered around with similar looking properties to:

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

But no joy.

[image: type of predictive bar at bottom of content page]

Many thanks!

Comment: @Jason Cheers for duplicate suggestion- not sure same issue. Whilst this may indeed be linked to a keyboard, there is no keyboard present on my screen... this bar kinda just floats there... hence question “what is it”. There is a spinner and one entry box on my page, so it obviously is linked to one of them.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, it is indeed the top of a keyboard. for some reason it is not appearing all the way on focus. THought it was something else, a new beast I'd never come across.